# Sitecore IFrame rendering HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: configuration, security, site-configuration

My application is using HTTPS.

The Sitecore sites configurations scheme are all set to HTTPS.

When I'm on Sitecore Management some internal sitecore iframes (Insert Link, Template Editor, Package Designer, Package Installer) doesn't work because the browser block it by using http instead of https (Mixed Content).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the site you run has this settings in the site definition:

```
<sites> 
<site name="website" scheme=”https”... /> 
</sites>
```

This parameter influences link formation by the LinkManager class. If this parameter is not defined in the web.config  section, then LinkManager can return a link in the following format: “://home.aspx” without the protocol identifier “http” or “https”.

[Scheme sdn](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/scheme.aspx)

You should also ensure that all traffic is served over SSL/TLS, open the Sitecore web.config file and edit the  section to include these attributes:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />
</system.web>
```

[Use HTTPS on all your Sitecore instances](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/use_https_on_all_your_sitecore_instances)

Comment: Please explain a bit more what your actual answer is - otherwise this will be treated as a link-only answer.